# How can I convert AVI files into MPGs with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, avi, file-conversion

I have this problem with some AVI files. The output of

```
ffmpeg -i file.avi
```

contains the line

> [NULL @ 0x97c4d40]Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected.

Someone advised me to use

```
ffmpeg -i file.avi -vcodec h263 -acodec aac -f mpg output.mpg
```

to convert the file to the correct format, but that produces the error

> Unknown input or output format: mpg

How can I convert my files?

Comment: Have you tried repairing the file? `ffmpeg -i infile.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy outfile.avi`

Comment: Yes, outfile.avi has the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

mpeg instead of mpg

`ffmpeg -i file.avi -vcodec mpeg4 -f mpeg output.mp4`

Comment: This writes error message: Unknown encoder 'aac'

Comment: I edited my answer - try

Comment: This writes: Error while opening codec for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Comment: `ffmpeg -i file.avi -vcodec mpeg4 -s 320x240 -b 300k -r 23.98 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 112k output.mp4` - you can play with size and bitrate

Comment: The same error.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Andreas Cadhalpun `ffmpeg` now has new filter: `mpeg4_unpack_bframes` (see [ref](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=0224b35c89e9e75f156962c93b37adab75d8df6a)).

Usage is as simple as:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.avi -codec copy -bsf:v mpeg4_unpack_bframes OUTPUT.mpg
```

Comment: I get `buffer underflow` error. When it finished converting, the video works, but there is no sound

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/). It's really simple. Although they haven't updated the software in a while, I've been using the same version for years (most recently on my Intel Mac with OS 10.6.6). It's good for individual files. Not sure about batching. Good luck.

> MPEG Streamclip is a powerful free video converter, player, editor for
>   Mac and Windows. It can play many movie files, not only MPEGs; it can
>   convert MPEG files between muxed/demuxed formats for authoring; it can
>   encode movies to many formats, including iPod; it can cut, trim and
>   join movies. MPEG Streamclip can also download videos from YouTube and
>   Google by entering the page URL.

Comment: I'm on Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case when I ran

```
ffmpeg -v 5 -i input.avi -f null -
```

and the following errors appeared:

```
[mpeg4 @ 02505f00] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
[null @ 024eb020] Encoder did not produce proper pts, making some up.
```

**The solution:**

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.avi output.mp4
```

As simple as that.

(Use `output.mpg` to convert to mpg.)